# Import error: cannot import name 'urllib' from 'moves' (unknown location)

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, urllib, six

This code:

```
import os, uuid
    from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient
```

Gives raise to following error:

> File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\policies_distributed_tracing.py",
> line 29, in   from six.moves import urllib
> ImportError:
> cannot import name 'urllib' from 'moves' (unknown location

Python version: 3.7.3

Pip freeze (excerpt):

- azure-core==1.8.1
- azure-storage-blob==12.5.0
- azure-storage-file-share==12.2.0
- azure-storage-queue==12.1.3
- six==1.15.0
- sixer==1.6.1
- urllib3==1.25.10

Any help on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
Noticed I get following error when just starting python from PowerShell:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> python
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Failed calling sys.__interactivehook__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site.py", line 408, in register_readline
    import readline
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\readline.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyreadline.rlmain import Readline
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import unicode_helper, logger, clipboard, lineeditor, modes, console
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .console import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\console.py", line 610, in <module>
    msvcrt = cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_msvcrt())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

Error still present after removing and installing python 3.7.3.
Python 2.7 is also installed

Comment: Looks like conflict between `six` and `sixer`. Can you remove `sixer` and check. It works for me.

Comment: Removed `sixer` but still get same error.

Comment: Hi! Could you share more details about your code? I tried the version like yours, and no error raised.

Comment: Hi, that is all the code, rest is commented out.

Comment: Placed update with error I get when just starting python in PowerShell, might be related....

Comment: Does `py -2.7` work well from the command line?

Comment: It looks like something isn't right with the `PATH` env variable. If you don't have the need to have multiple versions of Python, you may want to keep just the one that you want to work with and uninstall the others. You can have the installer configure the `PATH` variable with the “Add Python to PATH” option. The location of the `Scripts\` folder is also added that way. You should then be able to start Python from the command line. Check [Finding the Python executable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-the-python-executable)

Comment: Issue seems to be resolved.
Since this is on my work machine I needed admin rights to perform some actions which werent done automatically by the provided standard SW installer. Removed python 2.7, reinstalled 3.7 and installed azure.blob.storage package. Now all seems to work.

Comment: @Sanjuro Thanks for sharing what worked for you. Please post it as an answer so it also benefits others in the community.