# Fail to run six.moves import urllib in jupyter notebook

Tags: python

I run the code below and got the Error
in the area : "from six.moves import usrllib"
How do I fix this?

-------this is my code --------------------

```
import os
import tarfile
from six.moves import usrllib

DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/"
HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"

create housing_url ,housing_path
def fetch_housing_data(housing_url=HOUSING_URL, housing_path=HOUSING_PATH): 
    if not os.path.isdir(housing_path):
        os.makedirs(housing_path)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
    housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
    housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
    housing_tgz.close()
```

-----this is the Error --------------------

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/sg/vkph2xk90vz9179b84hndgn80000gn/T/ipykernel_4539/1326320674.py in 
1 import os
2 import tarfile
----> 3 from six.moves import usrllib
4
5 # DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/"

ImportError: cannot import name 'usrllib' from 'six.moves' (unknown location)

Comment: this one may be useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63898699/import-error-cannot-import-name-urllib-from-moves-unknown-location)

Comment: I guess the issue here is with the import name i.e., it should be `urllib` not `usrllib`.